# If both $f$ and $g$ are not integrable, then $f+g$ and $fg$ are not integrable

Tags: proof-verification

If both $f$ and $g$ are not integrable, then $f+g$ is not integrable

I think this is false. Take $f(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ 
0 & \text{ if } x \in \mathbb{Q}^c 
\end{cases}$ and $g(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } x \in \mathbb{Q}^c \\ 
0 & \text{ if } x \in \mathbb{Q} 
\end{cases}$
Then $f+g = 1$, which is integrable.

If both $f$ and $g$ are not integrable, then $fg$ is not integrable.
I think this is false, and I can take the same counterexample, and $fg = 0$, which is also integrable.

Are these correct?

Comment: If you mean integrable as in Riemann-integrable, then this seems correct!

Comment: Yup these are good!

Comment: I think you are right. And the argument also applies to Lebesgue-integrablity, simply replace $\mathbb Q$ by any non mesurable set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You examples are correct for Riemann integrability.

You can generalise your examples to Lebesgue integrability. Take, for example, any non-integable $f$ and put $g=-f$. Both $f$ and $g$ non-integrable, yet $f+g$ is integrable. You can also take two non-integrable functions $f$ and $g$ such their supports are disjoint (i.e. the sets where they are non-zero have empty intersection).  Their product is identically zero, hence integrable.

Answer (score 0):

Both your counterexamples are correct.